# How to get GitHub repository Directories via Octokit .Net API?

Tags: octokit.net

Can anyone tell me how to get GitHub repository's directories? Looking at the `client.Repository` API doesn't seem to have `dir` or it named differently?

Comment: Found it after I posted the question. Hope this will help others as well. `await client.Repository.Content.GetAllContents(...)`. By description, it returns the contents of a file or directory in a repository.